# Add vertical lines between table columns advanced pdf template netsuite using inline CSS

Tags: html, css, netsuite, suitescript

I want to add vertical line between each column. I need to use inline CSS as there are 2 tables. I want to apply lines to 1 table only. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a class name to the table where you want to the borders to appear.

```
<table class='barred'>
```

then in your css section

```css
.barred {border-collapse:collapse;}
.barred td{ border-left:1px solid black;}
```